# Pushing one instance of viewController to master and detailView Controller of splitViewcontroller

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

The scenario I'm stuck in is I want to push the one instance of `viewController` in `detailView` Controller and `masterView` controller of `splitViewController`. But what I have figured out that one instance of class can be pushed to only one of them in one time.  The whole situation is like a another `viewController` will be pushed to `deatilViewController` and the `viewController` which was in `detailViewController` will be moved to `masterViewController`. I have achieved this by using delays but I'm stuck when I click on back. `NavigationController` of `detailView` shows only one controller in its stack. I hope I'm making some sense. And thanks in advance.